# Flutter: Custom Nav Bar, how to make navigation, so that when you switch the button that you clicked on?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I need that after viewing the button, the screen switches along with the button. But here I switch the screen, but the button remains in the same place.

NavBar:

[image: NavBar]

How can this be fixed? (If you remove the navigation, then everything will work, they will not switch to screens)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class buildNavBarItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const buildNavBarItem({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _buildNavBarItemState createState() => _buildNavBarItemState();
}

class _buildNavBarItemState extends State<buildNavBarItem> {

  late int _selectedItemIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        NavBarItem(UniconsLine.pen, 0, PravoMainScreen()),
        NavBarItem(UniconsLine.home_alt, 1, OrganizationScreen()),
        NavBarItem(UniconsLine.setting, 2, JusticeMainScreen()),
      ],
    );
  }
  Widget NavBarItem(IconData icon, int index, Widget screen) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _selectedItemIndex = index;
        });
     Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => screen)
        );}, // Here it goes to another screen, but the button returns to the original
      child: Container(
          height: 50.0,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5.5,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: index == _selectedItemIndex ? Colors.white: Color(0xFF007FFF),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          child: Icon(icon, size: 44, color: index == _selectedItemIndex ? Color(0xFF007FFF): Colors.white),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you right, but in case you mean that the screen doesn't navigate to the called screen through the navbar, I think I might be able to help. I always made a file where the builder looks like this:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          pageList[widget.pageIndex],
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar:BottomNavigationBar(),
);
```

In pageList I have all of my screens and in the bottomnavigationbar I have the icons. `onTap` calls setstate and then the index is changed. Furthermore, the color of the icons is controlled with the index, which means I do something like:

```
decoration: value == widget.pageIndex
                            ? BoxDecoration(
                                color: primaryColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                              )
                            : BoxDecoration(
                                color: backgroundColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90)),
```

If not, just comment.